# Using a for-loop to plot several values in the same figure

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot

I am trying to plot a gravity anomaly by a method of trial and error in a `for` loop. I have below the formula for a gravity anomaly `gal1` caused by a round body, and I am trying to change the values of the mass (`m`) and the depth of the center of gravity (`h`) in the loop, so that it plots each value of the gravity anomaly for the different `m` and `h` inserted.

What happens is it does not plot any values using `plot(x,gal1(j)` and only plots one value when I do `plot(x,gal1)`. What I expect is for it to plot the values for each iteration in the loop so that I have various plots for different `gal1`

```
x=[-3 ; -2.5; -2; -1.5; -1; -0.5; 0; 0.5; 1.5];
    for j=1:9
        for i = 10:10:90
            for k = 10:10:90
                h(i)=i/100;
                m(k)=k/100
                gal1(j)=(6.67 * (m(k)) * (h(i))/(x(j, 1)^2 + (h(i)) ^2)^(3/2));
                plot(x,gal1(j))
                hold on
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: I am so sorry, it is MatLab, i was mistaken

Comment: You should be more precise than "It is not working". Also at the begining of your code you use `m`, `h` and `x`, but those variable doesn't exist yet. Provide a minimal and reproducible example of your problem.

Comment: Ok I corrected it, but m and h are specified in the loop, i want them to be the values varying from 0.1 to 0.9 in 0.1 steps

Comment: Your plot does not output anything because you're only plotting a point. You can display a point by using `plot(x,gal1(j),'o')`. But honestly your code is so weird and so inefficient, I'm almost sure that there is a bigger mistake somewhere. Since you do not provide the expected result I can't help more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, as [Adam mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59251137/5211833) that you are plotting a single point every time versus a complete array, thus it resulted in an error. Instead, calculate the whole array `gal1` and *then* plot it in its entirety.

```
x=[-3 ; -2.5; -2; -1.5; -1; -0.5; 0; 0.5; 1.5];
for j=1:9
    for i = 10:10:90
        for k = 10:10:90
            h(i)=i/100;
            m(k)=k/100;
            gal1(j)=(6.67 * (m(k)) * (h(i))/(x(j, 1)^2 + (h(i)) ^2)^(3/2));
        end
    end
end

figure;
plot(x,gal1,'-o') % - means a line, o gives dots on each measurement
```

Results in:

[image]

---

All those loops are overly verbose, difficult to read, easy to make errors in, and probably slower than a simple, vectorised, calculation:

```
x=[-3 ; -2.5; -2; -1.5; -1; -0.5; 0; 0.5; 1.5];
h = (0.1:0.1:0.9).';
m = (0.1:0.1:0.9).'; % =h?

gal1 = 6.67.*m.*h./((x.^2+h.^2).^(3/2));

figure;
plot(x,gal1,'-o')  % Same figure as above
```

Note that you create `h` and `m` before hand (they are equal though in this case?), be sure to transpose them to column vectors, just like you have `x`. Then simply use the same formula for `gal1`, and drop all indexing and replace operators by their element-wise counterparts by adding the dot in front of all the `*, /, ^` operators.

Using a bit of implicit-expansion magic, you can even plot all combinations of `h` and `m` directly:

```
x=[-3 ; -2.5; -2; -1.5; -1; -0.5; 0; 0.5; 1.5];
h = (0.1:0.1:0.9).';
m = (0.1:0.1:0.9); DO NOT transpose this

gal1 = 6.67.*m.*h./((x.^2+h.^2).^(3/2)); % is now 9x9

figure;
plot(x,gal1,'-o')
legend
```

Giving a plot for each column, i.e. differing `h` value:

[image]